# What is this "typedef void FuncType(double, int)" ?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I undestand what `typedef void (*p)(double, int)` means!
But I don't understand what `typedef void FuncType(double, int)` means!

Example:

```
void test(double, int) {}
typedef void FuncType(double, int);
//using FuncType = void(double, int);

int main() {
    FuncType *f = test;
    f(1, 3);
    FuncType ft;
    ft(10, 50);//ERROR: 'unresolved external symbol' during compilation process
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you have `using p = FuncType*;`

Comment: `FuncType ft;` is a declaration of a function `ft` which is never defined. You'll get the same error if you write the type directly, `void ft(double, int);`